# Regex to replace carriage returns

Tags: javascript, regex, carriage-return

I'm looking to improve a regex in JavaScript which looks for new lines or line breaks and replace them with carriage returns. - Yeah, Photoshop's text is old skool.

- "hello\nworld"
- "hello
  world"

Should all get replaced with

-hello/rworld

Yes, I'm aware the the second example above gets treated as an actual line break

So far I've had to use two regexs, whereas I really need one to look for both items (multiple times), but joining them together successfully it eludes me.

```
// replaces \n with \r carriage return
var rexp = new RegExp(/\\n/gi)
content = content.replace(rexp , "\r")

// replaces <br> with \r carriage return
rexp = new RegExp(/<br>/gi)
content = content.replace(rexp , "\r")
```

Thank you.

Comment: wouldnt the "or" operator work for you? /(\\n|<br>)/gi ?

Comment: I would if only I knew that's what I would need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ["special `|` or"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or) operator:

```
content = content.replace(/\n|<br\s*\/?>/gi, "\r");
```

It will successfully work for:

```
"hello\nworld"
"hello<br>world"
"hello<br />world"
```